# Cannot assign default value to property having RangeAttribute

Tags: c#

I have property with below details. If on edit, I remove value for DaysPerMonth field, I want it set to 0 as default value. But it gives me error - DaysPerMonth is required. Any leads here?

```
    [Range(typeof(int), "0", "31")]
    [DefaultValue(0)] <--- This doesn't work
    public override int DaysPerMonth {
        get; set;            
    }
```

Comment: have you tried this? 
public override int DaysPerMonth { get; set; } = 0;
or the type should be int? like this public override int? DaysPerMonth { get; set; }

Comment: Hi, Yes I have tried this too - DaysPerMonth { get; set; } = 0; This too didn't worked out. And no, this cannot be nullable property.

Comment: give some more code using this property and detailed exception description

Comment: There's literally nothing more than this code as such. In base class I have original property without decoration and this is class where I override it. The exception is exactly as I mentioned - DaysPerMonth is required. If you try it on your machine, I hope it will be easily reproducible like this. My main requirement is, if this in non-nullable int, and I open any record having this value, remove this field and save, it should save with 0 and should not throw range validator exception or required field message.

Comment: What version of C#/.Net are you using ?

Comment: .Net framework 4.7.2

Comment: Did you try to workaround by setting the value into the constructor ?

Comment: Yes that didn't worked too. I found that these values were already 0 when I tried to setting them in constructor. But on UI, those were blanks and range validator starts complaining there only. ModelStateDictionary ModelState.IsValid returns false and gives error on these 2 values.